# Find user with username in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Two relational tables are there User and Profile and the user name stored in profile.
I pass the username in route and used this code for getting the user but its showing me an error

**ERROR**

> "Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: Call to a
>   member function profile() on null in file ".

What's wrong in this code please check!!

```
public function update(Request $request, $user)
{
    $user = User::find(1)->profile()->where('username', $user);

    $user->update([
        'name' => $request->name,
        'email' => $request->email
    ]);

    // A User has a profile
    $user->profile()->update([
        'username' => $request->username,
        'location' => $request->location,
        'languages' => $request->languages,
        'about' => $request->about,
        'skills' => $request->skills,
        'available_for' => $request->available_for

    ]);

    return [
        'status' => true,
        'message' => 'User and profile updated',
    ];
}
```

Comment: Show us the model file of user and profile table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query does not make much sense, you fetch the user with the id `1` from the database and then search for the `username` in his profile, which will return `null` unless you get lucky and the user with the id `1` has the given `username`.

You can use something like this:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;

public function update(Request $request, $username)
{
    $user = User::whereHas('profile', function (Builder $query) use ($username) {
        $query->where('username', $username);
    })->firstOrFail();

    ...
}
```

It will search for a user with the given username in the profile table or throw a exception if it doesn't find one.

From the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence):

> If you need even more power, you may use the whereHas and orWhereHas methods to put "where" conditions on your has queries.
>   These methods allow you to add customized constraints to a
>   relationship constraint, such as checking the content of a comment:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;

// Retrieve posts with at least one comment containing words like foo%...
$posts = App\Post::whereHas('comments', function (Builder $query) {
    $query->where('content', 'like', 'foo%');
})->get();
```

Comment: right one!! go the answer. but any simple solution of that one and can you please tell me why "function ($query) use ($username)"

Comment: @John Not sure what you mean but I added a link to the documentation that explains `whereHas`.

Answer (score 3):

using `find` will search the model by it's primary key for a given id (like you search for userid 1). When you want to lookup with a differt attribute, you have to use the `where` function and when you want only the first one, use `first`.

```
$user = User::where('username', $user)->first();
```

or

```
$user = User::where('username', $user)->profile()->first();
```

Comment: The username seems to be stored in the profile table so this won't work.